# Jenkins - Execute (not trig) a job from a pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm looking for a way to execute a standard Jenkins job (freestyle project) from a pipeline.
I found the `build` command, but it does not execute the job, it triggers it. In my case, this lead to a deadlock, because I have only one node with one executor.

I really would like to execute the content of a freestyle project as a normal Step in my pipeline. I can't translate the freestyle project content into Windows bash, or Groovy, or whatever, cause it uses a plugin (proprietary) and, of course, I don't have any idea of what's happening in this plugin...

*in fine*, I would like to use the pipeline as a way to orchestrate freestyle projects, but with only one executor on one node.

Thanks !

Comment: Do you want to execute the freestyle project at the end of the pipeline ?

Comment: Why limit yourself to only one executor anyway? You can disable concurrent runs of the pipeline if you don't want the jobs to run out-of-order

Comment: @towel, it's an interresting way to consider the question, but if two pipelines (I mean, two different) run at the same time, it may lead to a deadlock too.

The freestyle project is a "single task", it is part of the pipeline, one step among many others

Comment: You can either throttle the number of runs of that particular freestyle project too, so that it becomes a critical point that is shared among the pipelines, or duplicate the freestyle project and have each pipeline its own copy (assuming that each copy can run independently.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you’re trying to trigger the freestyle job from within a node block. A freestyle job will afaik never be able to reuse that node block.

But maybe that’s not required anyway. What about just closing the node block first, trigger the build and reopen the node block afterwards if you still need it?